# change value of variable in forEach loop java 8

Tags: java, java-8

```
int count =0;
requestUserDto.getNodeIds().forEach(userNodeId->{
    count++; // this statement shows error
     // some another statements here
    }
});
```

why `count++` shows error

Error:

> Local variable i defined in an enclosing scope must be final or effectively final

Comment: Well, as the error message explains, you can't modify a local variable inside a lambda expression. If you'd mention what you are trying to do, perhaps we can suggest an alternative.

Comment: You could potentially use `AtomicInteger` instead, for example.

Comment: thanks But i know the alternative. i want to know why we cant change value here in forEach. In normal for each loop works fine

Comment: You can normally rearrange your code so a variable like that isn't required.

Comment: this is an example not an actual problem. only i want to know why lambdas only allow  effectively final variable.

Comment: @ArihantJain, you can simply use an array of `int` to update `arr[0]` in the `for` loop.

Comment: @ArihantJain There are good reasons why this limitation of local variables required to be effectively final was designed. [This article](http://www.lambdafaq.org/what-are-the-reasons-for-the-restriction-to-effective-immutability/) gives a fair explanation.

Comment: @MCEmperor thanks. this article gives me a clear explanation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Considering lambdas are essentially syntactic sugar for an anonymous inner class, a variable used in a lambda expression must be effectively final. Check out this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4732544/why-are-only-final-variables-accessible-in-anonymous-class) for more details.

Comment: so that means we can say this is the limitation or drawback of lambdas  that used variable is always effectively final.

Comment: I don't see it as a limitation in lambda since it just substitutes anonymous inner classes where non-final variables can not be defined. The behavior is logically correct.

Comment: @ArihantJain, such behavior is due to **how closures are handled in Java language**. There's an answer by Jon Skeet [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4732544/why-are-only-final-variables-accessible-in-anonymous-class/4732617)